# Improve opentok stream quality while publishing from video source

Tags: angularjs, video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing, opentok

I am using opentok to stream a video file `MediaStreamTrack`
Sample code:

```
        <video id="myPreview" controls ></video>

        const mediaStream = $('#myPreview')[0].captureStream()
        OT.initPublisher(el, {
              style: {
                nameDisplayMode: "on",
                buttonDisplayMode: "off",
              },
              // resolution: "320x240",
              // frameRate: 20,
              audioSource: mediaStream.getAudioTracks()[0],
              videoSource: mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0],
            });
```

It works fine but the problem is when viewers are around 20 the quality of video is pixelated.

More context:
I upload a video and use the blob to play the video in the preview.

I'm open for better solutions:

a. Upload video to server and stream edited moderate quality(not sure what to do) video in `myPreview`.

b. Upload video to 3rd party service and load video via their player.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enough bandwidth for publisher and subscribers. If one subscriber does not have enough bandwidth to receive VGA, for instance, it will receive a lower quality stream, but all the others should be fine. If publisher does not have a good upload bandwidth, then, it will be difficult for subscribers to receive good quality.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the minVideoBitrate on your publisher which will force a minimum bitrate. This is an integer value in bits per second. If there is a participant that cannot handle that minimum bitrate then they will drop to audio-only.

```
OT.initPublisher(el, {
  style: {
    nameDisplayMode: "on",
    buttonDisplayMode: "off",
  },
  minVideoBitrate: 2500000,
  audioSource: mediaStream.getAudioTracks()[0],
  videoSource: mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0],
});
```

Comment: There is no such option in `initPublisher`.